# Parsing a nested array in swift into decodable model

Tags: arrays, swift, decodable

Im calling the API here and the call is successful.When i print meetingData the status is good but when I print friends it shows all the values nil

```
AF.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
    let result = response.value
    print(result!)//my api call is successfull because its printing the result
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
        let meetingsData = try decoder.decode(Meetings.self, from: response.data!)
            print(meetingsData) 
        let friendsData = try decoder.decode(FriendDetail.self, from: response.data!)
            print(friends)
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

this is the model class Im using. In my response im able to print the status and message but unable to parse the JSON values in  **var friends: [FriendDetail]?** and **var meetings: [MeetingsDetail]?**

```
struct Meetings: Decodable {
    var status: Int
    var message: String
    var friends: [FriendDetail]?
}
struct FriendDetail: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var email: String
    var meetings: [MeetingsDetail]?
}
struct MeetingsDetail: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var mode: Int
    var meeting_with: String
}
```

And this is the API data which im trying to parse

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Friends found.",
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": 52,
            "email": "bilal@outlook.com",
            "meetings": [
                {
                    "id": 47,
                    "mode": 1,
                    "meeting_with": "Bbb"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://quicktype.io

Comment: `print(meetingsData.friends)`

Comment: BTW Your struct `MeetingsDetail` is missing the `id` property. And do you really need to declare those properties as optionals?

Comment: @LeoDabus it was quite a large list I have shorten down the values. 
and yes its printing meetingsData.friends

Comment: You don't need (and you can't) to parse them without parsing the root

Comment: You don't need to decode the json twice, access FriendsDetail from meetingsData

Comment: @JoakimDanielson to parse this data into tableview only meetingsData would work?

Comment: @MuhammadBilal I don't know what you mean by "only meetingsData would work?" As I already said you need to parse the root, but you don't need to parse all properties.

Comment: @LeoDabus please last question how do I access the meetings?

Comment: you mean the details?

Comment: yes @LeoDabus MeetingDetail

Comment: Do you have multiple friends? Are you trying to get all meeting from all friends?

Comment: yes there are multiple friends having meetings

Comment: `meetingsData.friends?.compactMap(\.meetings) ?? []` this will return a 2D array

Comment: if you would like them all in a single collection `let flatten = meetings.flatMap({$0})`